# Javascript: How to draw a simple line on canvas (in 3d) and make it rotatable (in 3d)?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, canvas, camera

So I want to draw a line on canvas (in 3d) and make it rotatable (in 3d) on mouse dragging that line (dragging some of its points) (better with out use of anything like a specialized lib - pure no libs JS...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good choice is the ["Three.js"](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) library; the [README](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js#readme) has a simple example of how to create a simple canvas-rendered scene. The ["Voxels"](http://mrdoob.com/129/Voxels_HTML5) example has mouse rotation; for fun, see the ["spikeball"](http://kile.stravaganza.org/lab/js/spikeball/) demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think [c3dl](http://www.c3dl.org) ([documentation](http://www.c3dl.org/index.php/documentation/)) will help you.